# Split pdf pages in two based on the content

Tags: python, pdf, split, edit, identify

I have to split multilingual PDFs to two different pdfs. I do have a function to split them but some of the files need to be split while others don't. How can identify based on their content does a pdf document needs to be split or not? It has to be done in python

samples:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AJ7ci6bQbRyRszIDIG_xqisKC2YsUzfO/view?usp=sharing this one needs to be split vertically so i can have Dutch and French separately

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tU2kGnUARKSa39-R78aGcaBZZInLH0xu/view?usp=sharing This one does not need to be split

samples:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AJ7ci6bQbRyRszIDIG_xqisKC2YsUzfO/view?usp=sharing this one needs to be split vertically so i can have Dutch and French separately

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tU2kGnUARKSa39-R78aGcaBZZInLH0xu/view?usp=sharing This one does not need to be split

Comment: If you already know how to read PDFs this isn't really a pdf question.  Are you stuck on language detection within text? Something else?

Comment: I want an automatic way to determine if the current file needs to be split or not.